# Unbreakable microwave safe plates?

Tags: equipment, microwave

I'd like to have plates with the following characteristics:

1. Don't break when you drop them on the floor
2. Do not get hot in the microwave (like normal china)
3. Durable and washable (not paper plates)

Do such plates exist? If so, where might I obtain some?

(edit) Ideally they would also look more or less like standard dinner plates.

Comment: You mean, like shallow tupperware? Or do you have further criteria (aesthetics, sturdiness)?

Comment: Looking for dinner plates, mostly. shouldn't bend, plain white/simple decorations (non-translucent) would be ideal. Also I like having a smaller lip. (more space for food)

Comment: I needed something I could buy a lot of so ebay was out. I found these: http://www.corelle.com/index.asp?pageId=61&pId=270 . Break, chip and scratch resistant, microwave safe, stacks nicely, doesn't look silly. Ordering some and will see how they turn out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One thing that hasn't been mentioned -- [Corelle](http://www.corelle.com/).

It's not completely unbreakable (and much like Pyrex, when it goes, it goes like what nico mentioned -- little tiny shards everywhere).

Supposedly, it loses its resilience to breaking over time, so newer plates are less likely to break when dropped as older ones, so this is one case where buying at a yard sale might not be best.

I don't know how the durability compares to Pyrex plates, but it looks more 'dinnerware-like' to start.

Comment: My parents have a set of Corelle, and I'm jealous of them.  Simple white, so can be used in a pinch for a nicer dinner.  They're also very thin so they stack very well for space savings.

Comment: Yeah this is what I just bought. The Pyrex stuff they apparently don't make anymore and I was trying to buy around 20 plates. Ebay would not have worked.

Comment: They're similar to Pyrex, especially in the breaking into a million tiny pieces department.

Comment: You people are making me want to buy a high-speed camera and break one on purpose. :P

Comment: +1 because my Corelle stuff has survived an unbelievable amount of punishment.  It's **possible** to chip or break, but extremely difficult.  The stuff is also very difficult to scratch, and immune to staining.  Even  turmeric won't leave the slightest discoloration.

Comment: @BobMcGee : not entirely impossible, but I have no idea how I did it.

Comment: @Joe: Are you sure it's not simply a thin layer of something stuck to the dish?  Things like caramel will leave a residue.  If so, running a Magic Eraser pad over it will usually take it off.

Comment: Ten minutes ago I dropped a small corelle plate on our kitchen floor (which is not a hard surface). This small plate shattered into hundreds of tiny sharp shards that went as far as 12' and two shards actually ended up on a high stool. This is the second time since I have owned this Corelle dinnerware that I have dropped and both times they shattered. I am replacing them. I have had them for years but with children and a dog I don't want to take the chance of one dropping again and a shard of glass ending up in someone's eye. It truly is unbelievable.

Comment: @Suzanne : do you know how old they were?  I'd be interested in trying to figure out if the rumors of them becoming more brittle over time are true

Answer (score 4):

The best plates I ever bought (that have all those characteristics you were asking for) were made by pyrex... Pyrex is obviously known for making great measuring cups and other glass bowls and things (and lab equipment like beakers)... But in college I found these translucent pyrex plates and they have lasted FOREVER!  They don't break, and they only need a few seconds to cool after coming from the microwave... Just google "Pyrex dinner plates", but here's one link I found:

http://www.etsy.com/listing/67297041/on-sale-now-pyrex-dinner-plates-with

Edit: I just looked a little harder... The plates I have are put out by Corning (but they are pyrex) and here's an ebay search of them:

http://shop.ebay.com/sis.html?_nkw=PYREX+CORNING+FESTIVA+Spring+Green+SALAD+PLATES

Comment: Pyrex plates are very resistent but when they break then it's a big mess, I can tell you! They tend to break up in million little pieces...

Comment: Thanks for the tip about Pyrex. Though I'll have to find some of their plates that look a little more like dinner plates.

Comment: There are some Pyrex plates with gold leaf around the edges. Probably not microwave safe I think. And everyone on ebay is selling in like lots of 1-4, which is annoying. I want like 12-16.

Answer (score 3):

With those requirements I'd start looking at "camping dishware" usually meant for camping and/or RV's; preferably in a polycarbonate material.

There's a line of products by GSI that are made with a polycarbonate resin.  This is (for all intents and purposes) the same material that those indestructible camping water bottles and chambro food containers are made out of.  There are loads of names for polycabonates, GSI calls it [infinity](http://www.gsioutdoors.com/technology/detail/infinity/).  Here is the [GSI infinity plate](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001UABE7W) and the [GSI infinity bowl](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004U7N2CW).

Comment: You can also find them in cookware places that specialize in boaters.  Of course, for boaters they might charge more.

Comment: It should be noted that if you're trying to stay away from BPA, polycarbonate is *not* the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Polypropylene dinner plates sound like they'd fit your requirements. Quick searching didn't find them in plain white, though. Polypropylene can be boiled, and should be fine in the dishwasher and microwave.

Other plastics would work too, and readily come in plain white. They are washable, but some specify hand-washing only, others top-rack only. You [find these on Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=node%3D367155011&field-keywords=plastic&x=0&y=0), [and some more too](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=plastic+dinner+plate&x=0&y=0).

I recommend trying a few first to be sure they take whatever abuse you need them to.

While plastic will *look* like a dinner plate, it won't *feel* like one, being far too light.

Answer (score 0):

Look for Inomata Folio series. They are polypropylene and comes in white too. It's very durable. It's Japan-made.

Comment: Can't find anywhere that says they are microwave safe...

Answer (score 0):

Carlisle polycarbonate is unbreakable and microwavable.  We used them at a Christian camp (institutional setting) and they can be bought in individual pieces at myBoelter.com.  They do have BPA, though.  Very durable and can be put into the dishwasher, too.